# PostgreSQL database not available through Navicat

Tags: database, postgresql, navicat

I'm new to Postgres, not to SQL. I generally use Navicat to connect to my databases, so I've set up a connection to a remote Postgres DB the same way I normally would. I'm able to:

- Connect successfully
- List databases

When I click on the database with my tables, however, it expands the database but doesn't show anything. No tables.

I saw the other question here, where a user was trying to get into 'template0' and 'template1': [Some PostgreSQL databases not visible through clients like Navicat or pgAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754010/some-postgresql-databases-not-visible-through-clients-like-navicat-or-pgadmin)

I'm not trying to get into these, but into a custom DB full of tables. I've verified that both my web app, and phpPgAdmin can both access all the tables and data, so the issue seems to lie with Navicat.

I read some instructions about how these tables might be 'system items', and went into the Navicat preferences and checked the box that says 'Show system items (PostgreSQL, SQL Server)' to no avail.

One thing I also tried, as I'm using Navicat Premium, is to install the Navicat PostgreSQL version instead. This also yields exactly the same results, I can see my database but none of the tables.

What's going on here?

*EDIT*

With some great help from Vao Tsun, we determined that this is PostgreSQL 7.2.4 and that it is not supported by Navicat.

Comment: when you `psql` with same credentials and `\dt` you see tables?..

Comment: Yes, \dt lists tables successfully when I'm SSH'd in directly and running via the terminal. When I connect to the the database via Navicat, I can right click on the DB and open a console (which essentially brings me to the same prompt as I'd have in a terminal). From here, running \dt does nothing. I can, however, run queries select * from table; which return results just fine. It's almost as if I don't have permission to list tables, though on the exact same account via the terminal I have the functionality. I can't explain the disconnect between the two as they should essentially be the same

Comment: curiouser and curiouser!

Comment: you you use ssh?.. If your Navicat can connect, then local psql can as well?..

Comment: It's very strange! I'm SSH tunneling with Navicat using the exact same credentials that I use when I manually SSH. The PSQL credentials also match what I use via the terminal manually.

Comment: I thought for sure it was the "Show system items (PostgreSQL, SQL Server)" setting in Navicat once people told me to check that to allow it to list tables. But alas, it connects fine, shows me my schema, but won't show me a single table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143580/discussion-between-vao-tsun-and-carbide20).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-for-postgresql:

> Navicat for PostgreSQL connects you to any local/remote PostgreSQL
>   database servers from version 7.3 or above.

It does not work with PostgreSQL 7.2.4